# How do I read data from a file with description and blank lines with Fortran 77?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am new to Fortran 77. I need to read the data from a given text file into two arrays, but there are some lines that either are blank or contain descriptive information on the data set before the lines containing the data I need to read. How do I skip those lines?

Also, is there a way my code can count the number of lines containing the data I'm interested in in that file? Or do I necessarily have to count them by hand to build my do-loops for reading the data?

I have tried to find examples online and in Schaum's *Programming with Fortran 77*, but couldn't find anything too specific on that.

Part of the file I need to read data from follows below. I need to build an array with the entries under each column.

```
    Data from fig. 3 in Klapdor et al., MPLA_17(2002)2409

    E(keV)  counts_in_bin

    2031.5  5.4

    2032.5  0

    2033.5  0
```

I am assuming this question is very basic, but I've been fighting with this for a while now, so I thought I would ask.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to use a standard that is 40 years old?

Comment: It's the standard being used in this class I am taking.

Comment: Are the locations of the lines that are blank fixed (e.g. predictable) or random?

Comment: You can use END= in your READ statement to check for end of file. Will try and post something later.

Comment: @casey The locations are fixed.

Comment: @TomSharpe That would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know where the lines are that you don't need/want to read, you can advance the IO with a call to `read` with no input items.

You can use:

```
read(input-unit,*)
```

to read a line from your input file, discard its contents and advance IO to the next line.

Comment: This actually was the solution I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Just did. Thanks for letting me know. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time since I have looked at F77 code, but in general if your read statement in a DO loop can deal with finding empty lines, or even a record that contains only blanks, then you could write logic to trap that condition and go to a break or continue statement. I just don't recall if read can deal with the situation intelligently.

Alternatively, if you are using a UNIX shell and coreutils, you can use sed to remove empty line, /^$/
or /^ *$/ to preprocess the file before you send it onto F77

Something like

$ sed infile -e 'd/^$/;d/^ *$/' > outfile

Answer (score 1):

It should look something like this:-

```
C       Initialise
    integer i
    character*80 t1,t2,t3
    real*8 x,y
    open(unit=1,file='qdata.txt')   
C       Read headers    
    read(1,100)t1
100 format(A80)
    write(6,*) t1
    read(1,100)t2
    write(6,*) t2
    read(1,100)t3
    write(6,*) t3
    write(6,*)

C       Read data
    do 10 i=1,10
    read(1,*,end=99) x,y
    write(6,*) x,y
10  continue
99  continue
    end
```

So I've used a classic formatted read to read in the header lines, then free-format to read the numbers. The free-format read with the asterisk skips white space including blank lines so it does what you want, and when there is no more data it will go to statement 99 and finish.

The output looks like this:-

```
     Data from fig. 3 in Klapdor et al., MPLA_17(2002)2409                       

     E(keV)  counts_in_bin 

   2031.5000000000000        5.4000000000000004     
   2032.5000000000000        0.0000000000000000     
   2033.5000000000000        0.0000000000000000
```